# displaying file content in svelte

Tags: file, svelte, read-eval-print-loop

I am using this code to upload a file. And I want to display the content of the file but all I get is [object file] and nothing else. is there a way to display the file content in svelte?

file text2.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 1
```

Test.svelte:

```
    <script>
      import { onMount } from "svelte"
      // d3.csv(' http://127.0.0.1:8081/test.csv').then(function(data) {
      //   console.log(data[0])})
    
      let files;
      $: if (files) {
        console.log(files);
        for (const file of files) {
          console.log(`${file.name}: ${file.size} bytes`);
        }
      }
    
    </script>
    
    <p>...from test</p>
    
    <input type='file' bind:files>
    
    {#if files}
        <h2>Selected files:</h2>
        {#each Array.from(files) as file,i}
            <p>{file.name} ({file.size} bytes)</p>
                    <p>e: {file} i: {i}</p>
        {/each}
        <p>files length: {files.length}</p>
    {/if}
```

To reproduce this, just paste it into a svelte REPL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After uploading a file you get an object of the type [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), this is what allows you to do `file.name` and `file.size`. To get the actual content of this file you have to open a stream and then handle this stream. For simple files you can also you use `.text()` method which returns a *promise* that resolves with the text content. That means that you could use this promis in an `#await` block from 'svelte'

```html
{#each Array.from(files) as file, i}
  <p>{file.name} {file.size} bytes</p>
  {#await file.text() then text}
    <p>e: {text} i: {i}</p>
  {/await}
{/each}
```

Comment: ok, that seems to work. but why is this so hard to find in the docs? this is a simple operation in any other regular language, but here it is almost impossible to find out how.

Comment: Very useful, as @JonasFredriksson mentioned, this appears to be quite absent from the docs.